# MacOSX Tkinter no response when Tk()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `TkButton.py` like this

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text = 'Python/Tkinter')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But when I execute `python2.7 TkButton.py`, it just stuck.
[image]

I installed Python2.7 and py27-tkinter using MacPorts.
My OS is `OS X 10.11.6`

Can somebody help me?

**Addition**
Tkinter.Tk() not working. I don't know why.
[image]
And I can't write any command after `root = tk.Tk()`, so I have to `Ctrl-C` to quit.

Comment: use `print()` to see which part is executed and which not.

Comment: @furas Sorry, my fault. I add an new image for the problem.

Comment: your second image doesn't show that it stuck. System shows `>>>` so `root = tk.Tk()` was executed. What did you expect ? Can't you write next command ?

Comment: @furas I can't write anything after that.

Comment: I don't have Mac to test it. Normally `Python` has `Tkinter` installed and you don't have to install it manually. Maybe try [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) - it should install `Python` with `Tkinter` (and other precompiled modules)

Comment: BTW: if you had to install `Tkinter` manually then maybe you have to install manually `tcl/tk` which is used by `Tkinter`.

Comment: @furas I found something weird. I have two python2.7. One is `python` which is pre-installed by Mac, and its version is `2.7.10`. This one works fine with the code above, and can output a small window. The other one (the problem one) is `python2.7` installed by `MacPorts`, and its version is `2.7.13`.

Comment: there is nothing new in `2.7.13` what you would need - so you can use `2.7.10`

Comment: @Jiang could you try in your console to do: `python2.7 -m pip install Tkinter` (might need admin rights) it should install tkinter and its dependencies

Comment: @furas there might be conflicts in name resolution depending on which one is linked to the command, as in one of them might be incorrectly installed and missing something (like maybe tcl/tk or something)

Comment: @Mixone I tried that, and still doesn't work. It seems that `python2.7` from `MacPorts` doesn't work well with `Tkinter`(also from MacPorts)